# pgAdmin/psql how to import new column's data to existing records?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, psql, pgadmin

I have several tables in a database of PostgresQL that contains users' records. I would like to add a new column to user's table and was wondering how I can import data of that new column.

I have a CSV file but can't work out the best way to import the data without overwriting any existing records.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your request is possible with a single `psql` command, but I think you can achieve what you're going for in a few steps.

1. Create temporary table in your db matching the CSV structure (I'm assuming the CSV contains 2 columns, a primary key and the new column data)
2. Populate this temporary table with the CSV data using postgres' [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) command
3. Run an `UPDATE` query to copy the data from the temporary table into your existing table
4. `DROP` the temporary table and you're done!

[sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fa5585/1)

DDL

```
-- existing table in your db
create table my_table (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  some_col integer
);

-- some dummy data
insert into my_table (id, some_col)
values (1, 111), (2, 222), (3, 333);

-- create temp_table with same structure as CSV
create table temp_table (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  new_col_val text
);

-- some dummy data, but you can use postgresql's COPY command to copy data from a CSV
-- docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html
insert into temp_table (id, new_col_val)
values (1, 'hello'), (2, 'hi'), (3, 'hey');
```

Queries

```
-- view initial contents of my_table
select * from my_table;

-- view initial contents of temp_table
select * from temp_table;

-- add new column to my_table
alter table my_table add column new_col text;

-- populate new column with data from temp_table
update my_table set new_col = new_col_val
from temp_table
where my_table.id = temp_table.id;

-- view results
select * from my_table;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer, it works!!!! Thank you again for your kind help, you saved my day!!!!!